# Reset DHCP cache for Asus Memo Pad HD7 'Avoided due to poor connection'

Tags: wi-fi, dhcp

Only the other day, my tablet now refuses to connect to any Wi-Fi spot.

I've tried resetting both the tablet and the router to no avail. After looking around, it seems to be some form of issue with the DHCP, as I can connect via a static IP address, but obviously this only helps on my home connection.

I'm just wondering if anyone knows how to clear the DHCP cache if that's even possible? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem when using my Asus MemoPad HD7. For home connection a static IP worked fine, however this was not acceptable.
I did a bit of research and found out it should be possible after gaining root access to the device to delete the corresponding cache file.

As I needed a fast solution I just did a factory reset of the Pad, which resolved the issue for me.